# can't get session value in express router

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, cookies

in my app.js:

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'luoxia.me',
  key: 'hackthon',
  cookie:{
   maxAge:1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30
  },
 store:new MongoStore({
   db: 'hackthon',
   host:'localhost',
   port: 27520,
   username: 'haha',
   password: 'luoxia.me'
 })
}));
```

and I set the admin value in the /api/auth:

```
req.session.admin = true;
```

but I can't get the admin value of req.session in other router like /api/getUsers, it's always undefined, but I can get the value in '/admin' the cookie of this site's path is '/', so how could this happen?

Answer (score 0):

where do you use the req.session.admin = true; ?

do you can to put the complete function?

remove the return, when you use res param finish the function.

```
app.get('/api/auth',function(req,res){ 
    const passwd = req.body.passwd; 
    if(passwd === 'luoxia.me'){ 
      req.session.admin = true; 
      res.status(200).end(); 
    } else { 
      res.status(401).end(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: in router /api/auth, module.exports = function(req,res){
    const passwd = req.body.passwd;
    if(passwd === 'luoxia.me'){
        req.session.admin = true;
 
        return res.status(200).end();
    } else {
        return res.status(401).end();
    }
}

Comment: you must have  app.get('/api/auth', require("moduleName");  or    app.get('/api/auth',function(req,res){ 
 const passwd = req.body.passwd; 
  if(passwd === 'luoxia.me'){ 
    req.session.admin = true; 
    return res.status(200).end(); 
  } else { 
    return res.status(401).end(); 
  }
});

Comment: of course I do, I use express.Router, in app.js : app.use('/api', apiRouter), then in apiRouter: router.get('/auth',auth), finally, export the router to app.js

Comment: remove the returns as in the example

Comment: it's useless, oh

Comment: try to use the example without your own modules. In my server it work, I don't understand why not to you.

Comment: do you have checked if enter in the condition?

Comment: I had found the solution, I use fetch API in the front end , and the Fetch API won't take cookie unless I config it